# How to change range of an colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, figure, colorbar

I'm trying to create a plot of ocean surface nitrate (downloaded from NOAA). I'm having trouble adjusting the colorbar while keeping the other elements of the plot. I would like the colorbar to range from 0-8, with all values > 8 to be represented as the top end of the color spectrum.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

nit = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds-ocean/dodsC/ncei/woa/nitrate/all/1.00/woa18_all_n00_01.nc'

nitr= xr.open_dataset(nit, decode_times=False)
nitr

variables = ['n_an']
nitr[variables]

nitr_5 = nitr.n_an.sel(depth=5,  method='nearest')
nitr_5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()
nitr_5.plot(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), vmin=2, vmax=30, cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.4}, cbar)
ax.set_title("")
```

The above code should hopefully be reproducible-- when I try to do this using the .colorbar argument it gives me a separate, blank colorbar so I am looking for a solution that I will be able to implement with the dataset!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you not get your desired result when you set `vmin=0` and `vmax=8`?

Answer (score 0):

The xarray package is controlling the colorbar via the `cbar_kwargs` dictionary, which is passed to `matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar`. By checking its [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) you can find the relevant arguments `ticks` and `extend`. Try using these `cbar_kwargs`:

```py
cbar_kwargs={'shrink': 0.4, 'ticks': list(range(9)), 'extend': 'max'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! This combined with altering 'vmin' and 'vmax' in the .plot() line fixed my issue.